# How to combine Boostrap Carousel and Jquery animate()

Tags: html, jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate

I am learning the carousel Bootstrap. I have an idea that when each slide item is showed, the caption will also have some animation, such as fadeIn, slideUp, or using animate() API of jQuery. I tried the animate() But the problem is that the these animation only run one time when page load. Can you please suggest how to make the animate() will run repeated when the slide item is shown.

I am learning this:
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_carousel2&stacked=h

Thank you so much

Comment: add code you have tried

Comment: Yes sure you can see here: https://repl.it/repls/LittleVirtualVoxel#index.html.  
 Please focus on first slide, its caption is only animated when the slide is show firs time, for the next times, it doesn't.